# Adhering to a Repository Pattern for a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, repository-pattern

I'm creating a class using the Repository Pattern for SharePoint lists (as opposed to directly accessing an actual table in a database) on a collection of list items. The Repository Pattern designs that I've seen are constantly creating a new context for each individual repository, but I would like to use the same ClientContext object for each of the concurrent repositories (one for each list) that might be in existence. Assuming I don't want someone to have to create a new ClientContext instance themselves which would be passed into the SPRepository class as a constructor, what other options do I have as far as keeping it in static memory?

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx
https://hendrikbulens.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/repository-pattern-sharepoint/ (This one makes use of separate repositories for each list whereas I want to make a more generic one which accepts a list name in the constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more complex subject than it seems, as there are many things to consider. Most of the solutions I've seen (including your links) are trying to make code generic with the cost of performance and resource consumption. There is no one-fits-all solution.

#### Single responsibility

You should inject `ClientContext` into your repository because there are many different authentication scenarios for CSOM (NTLM, FBA, ADFS, high trust app with user identity, High trust app with app identity, just to name few). Repository shouldn't be aware of the authentication method and means of creating the context.

#### Resources

Sharing one instance of `ClientContext` between multiple repositories may be good idea in simple scenarios when you want to avoid creating unnecessary objects. It implements `IDisposable` and we should assume there is a reason for that.

#### Number of `ExecuteQuery()` calls

If you use one `ClientContext` instance for multiple repositories you can schedule multiple operations and execute them all with one request to SharePoint.

```
var result1 = repository1.ScheduleLoad();
var result2 = repository2.ScheduleLoad();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Remember that CSOM is remote API. Number of calls and amount of data retrieved will have significant impact on performance.

#### Calls to `ExecuteQuery()` from other objects or threads

Consider this:

```
var web = StaticClass.Context.Web;
var list = web.GetList('Lists/example');
var item = list.GetItemById(1);

item["Title"] = "Test";

var result = repository.GetItemsAndExecute();
//or some other thread calls StaticClass.Context.ExecuteQuery();

item.Update();
StaticClass.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

What will be the result? Value of `Title` field will remain empty. Here's why:

- First call gets the item by id and sets the field value, but it does not call `Update()`.
- Second call gets the item by id **again** and calls `Update()`, but it does not set the field value.